# Unexpected results with betweenness_centrality

Tags: python, networkx

Below is code to create a very simple graph in networkx using Python 2.7 with a call to return betweenness_centrality:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,3])
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G[1][2]['weight']=4400
G[2][3]['weight']=4100
G[1][3]['weight']=1500
print nx.betweenness_centrality(G,weight='weight')
```

I expected to see weights essentially as assigned, but the weights are all zero:

{1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}

I am clearly missing something simple, and cannot see what it is from the on-line documentation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The default for `networkx.betweenness_centrality()` (and arguably the standard definition) does not include counting the endpoints.  So with your K3 graph the betweenness on each node is 0.  If you want to count endpoints use

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_nodes_from([1,3])

In [4]: G.add_edge(1,2)

In [5]: G.add_edge(2,3)

In [6]: G.add_edge(1,3)

In [7]: G[1][2]['weight']=4400

In [8]: G[2][3]['weight']=4100

In [9]: G[1][3]['weight']=1500

In [10]: print(nx.betweenness_centrality(G,weight='weight',endpoints=True))
{1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0}
```

Note that the 'weight' attribute is used to find the shortest path and not counted directly in the betweenness score.  For example with nonsymmetric paths in a loop:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.cycle_graph(4)

In [3]: nx.set_edge_attributes(G,'weight',1)

In [4]: print(nx.betweenness_centrality(G,weight='weight'))
{0: 0.16666666666666666, 1: 0.16666666666666666, 2: 0.16666666666666666, 3: 0.16666666666666666}

In [5]: G[0][1]['weight']=5

In [6]: print(nx.betweenness_centrality(G,weight='weight'))
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.6666666666666666, 3: 0.6666666666666666}
```